# Is it normal for my SQL Query to be this slow?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I'm having a problem with the system being overloaded.
The query below is getting data from 3 tables, 2 of them have more than 10.000 records, and it takes 50 seconds to run.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
p.prod_name,
p.prod_price,
Sum(dt.vt_qtd) as total_qtd

FROM tdb_products p 
LEFT JOIN tdb_sales_temp dt ON p.prod_mp_id = dt.vt_product
LEFT JOIN tdb_sales s ON dt.vt_cupom = s.sl_coupom

WHERE
s.sl_day = $day_link AND
s.sl_mon = $mon_link AND
s.sl_year = $year_link

GROUP BY
p.prod_name

ORDER BY
p.prod_name ASC
```

Is this normal?

Resolved!

Comment: What indexes do you have?

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` is slower than `INNER JOIN`. `GROUP BY` can be very slow on large tables. Insure that you need those things before you use them.

Comment: I notice you are using separate day, month, and year columns in the WHERE clause. If those were combined as a single `DATE` column with an index, it could have a big impact (plus the benefit of all the DATE functions)

Comment: Do you need the `DISTINCT` since you are using `GROUP BY`?

Comment: yes. If you group on the product id and remove the distinct it might (just might) get faster.

Comment: What database are you using? This should be in your tags for every question like this.

Comment: @halfter: since the database happily accepts grouping on prod_name and selecting both prod_name and prod_price, it's probably MySQL.

Comment: @halfer: ungrouped `prod_price` in the `SELECT` list pretty much explains it I think

Comment: @PaulTomblin unfortunately, None.

Comment: @Quassnoi/fdreger - didn't know that. Nevertheless, no harm in recommending good asking practices `:)`

Comment: How are you determining run time? I had this issue very recently and had a query I thought was slow until I ran it on the CLI and it ran in under a second and turned out it was my script (specifically Datatables) and not MYSQL causing the problems

Comment: @halfer MYSQL, sorry for that!

Comment: @Jason, I got the time under NAVICAT and with PHP microtime function

Comment: @PaulTomblin I've created the indexes and te response time droped to 1 sec. THANK YOU!!!!

Comment: @evdutcos You don't need to add "Resolved" in the question. Just tick (accept) the answer that helped you most. (Oh, you already did, nice)

Comment: **You need to show us the table and index definitions.**  Diagnosing slow queries requires full table and index definitions, not just a description or paraphrase.  Maybe your tables are defined poorly.  Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly.  Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did.   Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer is no, that is definitely not an okay length of time.  Any common database system should be able to handle multiple 10,000 row tables with sub-second time.

Not knowing the full schema or dbms back end, my recommendations to look at would be:

Indexing - make sure that the columns being used in the joins have proper indexes on them
Data Type - if there is a difference in data type on the columns being joined, the dbms will have to perform a conversion for each row connection which could lead to significant performance drain.

Answer (score 10):

```sql
SELECT  prod_name, prod_price, SUM(dt.vt_qtd) AS total_qtd
FROM    tdb_sales s
JOIN    tdb_sales_temp dt
ON      dt.vt_cupom = s.sl_coupom
JOIN    tdb_products p
ON      p.prod_mp_id = dt.vt_product
WHERE   (s.sl_day, s.sl_mon, s_sl_year) = ($day_link, $mon_link, $year_link)
GROUP BY
        p.prod_name -- but it's better to group by product's PRIMARY KEY
```

Remove `DISTINCT` (it's redundant as you have `GROUP BY` and select the grouping field)

Rewrite `LEFT JOIN` as `INNER JOIN` since you have a filtering condition on a `LEFT JOIN`'ed table.

Create indexes:

```sql
tdb_sales (sl_year, sl_mon, sl_day, sl_coupom)
tdb_sales_temp (vt_cupom, vt_product)
tdp_product (prod_mp_id) -- it's probably a PRIMARY KEY and you already have it
```

Comment: OMG!! I've created the indexes and te response time droped to 1 sec. THANK YOU!!!!

Comment: Why creating a simple index drop the time? There is a limit for that? Thanks again!

Comment: @evdutcos: because that's what indexes are for, improving performance. Have you rewritten the query as well?

Comment: @evdutcos Yes, there is a limitation to creating indexes: the server must maintain the indexes, and so it makes individual insert/update/delete queries each just a little slower... but as you can see, for careful use of indexes the improvement on the select side is dramatic.